# Spring Data Elasticsearch : path.home is not configured error

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I've tried to create a sample project using Spring Data Elasticsearch but didn't able to proceed due to `path.home is not configured` error. My elasticsearch version is **2.3.3**. I've used annotation to create bean as follow :

```
@Bean
public static NodeBuilder nodeBuilder() {
    return new NodeBuilder();
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(getNodeClient());
}

@Bean
private static NodeClient getNodeClient() {
    return (NodeClient) nodeBuilder().clusterName(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).local(true).node().client();
}
```

My spring-data-elasticsearch version :

[image]

Did i miss anything there?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the path as a setting for the NodeBuilder:

```
@Bean
public Settings elasticsearchSettings() {

     Settings.Builder elasticsearchSettings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
         .put("path.home", "/foo/bar");

        return elasticsearchSettings.build();
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {

    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
        .settings(elasticsearchSettings()).node().client());
}
```

If you use Spring Boot, [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-elasticsearch-spring-data) describes the usage of a .properties file:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.home=/foo/bar
```